# How to make an Infographic "Wide" in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Just a quick question for people who have any experience with this. I'm getting an infographic designed for my blog and noticed that other people have a function to make the infographic go to a full width template at the click of a button.

Here's an example:

https://blog.kissmetrics.com/science-of-brands-on-instagram/

If you click on the infographic, rather than going directly to the image page, it loads the header and changes the template to a full width. I noticed that the URL query goes to ?wide=1.

Is this a plugin or a built in function in Wordpress? Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say if it's a plugin or the template just naturally displays clicked images like that, but I think I might consider doing a javascript instead. That way you don't move off the page when enlarging and image. Something like this:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8w0ay8xs/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
.mycol  {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.myimg  {
    width: 500px;
}
.allwide    {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px auto;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    float:left;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    border: 10px solid #FFF;
    min-width: 700px;
}
</style>
<div class="mycol">
<h1>Infographic: The Science of Brands on Instagram</h1>
<p>No other social platform provides an experience as incredibly focused and engaging as Instagram. With just a bit of creativity and thoughtful measuring, you can make some Insta-magic for your brand. In this infographic, discover the trends behind the big-brand Instagram experience and learn how you can catapult your company to new heights.</p>

<p>Click on the infographic below to view a larger image:</p>
<img src="http://www.jpeg.org/images/jpeg-home.jpg" class="myimg" />
</div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".myimg").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("allwide");
    });
});
</script>
```